# How to preserve key in TPM 2.0

Tags: key-management, .net, tpm

I've been looking into TPM 2.0 with .NET ([TSS.MST](https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR)), and I don't understand how to preserve key upon application rerun. TSS.MST provides a [binary](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52507) simulating the TPM2.0 device and the app is connecting over TCP.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758451/how-can-i-persist-tpm-keys-on-disk-using-net-and-tpm2lib) it is said you're not supposed to preserve keys but to regenerate them. On the contrary, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR/blob/03f5093cee0a607205cfc620c3c75cabf9499d61/Tpm2Tester/TestSubstrate/TestSubstrate.cs#L1122) they store the key handle into NVm.

This has me a little bit perplexed.

If I want to keep the key in the NVm, should I serialize it as a byte array? (I had some bad luck with that since `Context` class does not have serialize property)

How am I supposed to regenerate the keys?
I would really appreciate any help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have decided to export only the key handle. Making the key persistent and then storing the ID of the handle (handle.handle member variable) and upon application rerun assigning the handle id to a new handle.

More detailed implementation [here](https://github.com/kostamoisidis/TSSExamples)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).